# Dúvidas sobre geração de programa executável no VBA/Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, compilação, instalador

Compilei um programa em VBA que interage com uma planilha do Excel. Após não ter mais falhas apontadas ao compilar, a compilação é executada e nenhuma ação é apresentada ao final.

Não localizei o programa executável em nenhuma pasta (caso ele tenha sido gerado).

Ao pesquisar sobre o assunto, fiquei com mais dúvidas:

É possível gerar o programa executável do VBA que faz uso de planilhas do Excel? Há indicações que nestes casos um Excel de versão compatível tem de estar instalado em cada computador em que irá ser executado, justamente por fazer uso da planilha e necessitar do Excel.

Se a compilação gerou o programa executável, onde está sendo salvo o arquivo? Há indicações de nomes de diretórios que não localizei, por exemplo, "BIN".

Gostaria de saber o que de fato ocorre e como devo proceder para gerar e instalar em outros computadores o programa gerado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O VBA, que significa [*Visual Basic for Applications*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), é uma linguagem interpretada criada pela Microsoft para permitir a automação de alguns processos em suas aplicações (dai o nome Visual Basic para Aplicações). Por ser uma linguagem interpretada, não há a geração de executável. Um módulo específico, compartilhado por todas as aplicações que utilizam o VBA, é responsável por interpretar o código escrito nessa linguagem, *diretamente a partir da aplicação que o utiliza*. Por isso o VBA tem as instruções/comandos genéricas(os) e os(as) específicos(as) de cada aplicação (no Excel, há classes para manipular planilhas, no Word, pra manipular estilos de texto, no Powerpoint para manipular formas e slides, etc).

Eu desconheço se há algum compilador VBA robusto ou que funcione bem, mas desconfio que se houver serão poucos. Afinal, se a sua idéia é fazer um executável, você pode usar qualquer outra linguagem (inclusive Visual Basic) pra acessar e/ou manipular arquivos do Office via bibliotecas específicas. O único uso para uma compilação de código VBA em executável que eu enxergo seria para dificultar o acesso ao seu código, mas mesmo assim é possível proteger os projetos dentro das ferramentas do Office e conseguir esse comportamento sem precisar gerar nada externo.

De todas as formas, ao fazer uma busca no Google encontrei algumas opções como esse tal de [VbaCompiler](http://vbacompiler.com/) (que parece gerar uma DLL a partir do código). Não o conheço, e não sei se funciona como esperado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, vou verificar o que indicou.

Comment: Realmente há soluções para proteger o código por meio da geração de executável (por exemplo, o Secure++ VBA For Microsoft Office Excel & PowerPoint), mas eles necessitam do office para serem executados da mesma forma. Alguns comentam que além da proteção há o ganho de performance. Eu me interessei em passar a usar o VB em casos específicos, mas a dúvida é se o VB é uma linguagem que tem suporte e atualizações ou é como o VBA, que foi descontinuado (parece que a última versão do VB é de 2010). Quais seriam outras opções para substituir o VB se for o caso, pois li que o Delphi foi descontinuado.

Comment: O VB foi continuado por meio do .NET (como uma linguagem adicional para a construção do código). Dê uma pesquisada a respeito.

Comment: Ok. Vou ver. Grato